# Install PhoneGap to VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, angularjs, cordova, installation, windows-phone

Hi all I am new for `PhoneGap`

I will try to create Windows Phone app by using `PhoneGap` with `AngularJs` (it's my requirement and my OS is `Windows 8` )

I have some knowledge about `angularjs`, But nothing have knowledge about `phonegap`.

I want to install PhoneGap  to `Visual Studio 2012`. and what will do next?

And please any one explain how to start the Windows phone app using `PhoneGap` and `AngularJs`?

and what is the meaning for **cordova and phonegap** ? Am confused.

Always am waiting look like :(

[image]

Comment: Why don't you read the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide) first?

Comment: @asgoth  I have confused with `what is the meaning for cordova and phonegap `  So i asked to here. cool dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Visual studio 2010 or Visual studio 2013. im not sure about angular havent used it before, but it seems like js library so i dont see why you cant use it.

for installing phonegap on visual studio 2010 windows 7 os

make sure you have installed visual studio 2010 sp1.

Download windows phone emulator sdk 7. from http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=27570

download phonegap files from phonegap.com

after downloading open the phonegap files go to lib/windows phone and run createtemplates windows batchfile and it will create two zip files. 
copy the cordova 7 zip file to documents/visual studio 2010/Templates/ projects Templates.

then run vs 2010 new project You should be able to see the template Cordova wp7, if not search it on your right hand searchbar. and create new project.
 Wola thats it.

Note- not sure how to add plugins if someone knows please add comment

---

windows 8

for installing phonegap on visual studio 2013 windows 8 os

make sure you have installed visual studio 2013 preferrably you must have Update 4 installed

Download windows phone emulator sdk 8. from http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=35471

download phonegap files from phonegap.com

after downloading open the phonegap files go to lib/windows phone and run createtemplates windows batchfile and it will create two zip files. 
copy the cordova 8 zip file to documents/visual studio 2013/Templates/ projects Templates.

then run vs 2013 new project You should be able to see the template Cordova wp8, if not search it on your right hand searchbar. and create new project.
 Wola.... thats it.

Note to add plugins - download Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0  http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=42675

---

Not that if you running windows 7  you will not be able to debug with sdk 8 emulator- just browser